# What is the smallest $n = pq$ for which the RSA encryption and decryption works?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The example at https://www.di-mgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#simpleexample claims that the smallest value for the modulus $ n $ for which the RSA algorithm works is $ n = 11 \times 3 = 33 $.

But slide number 30 (page 30) of http://haifux.org/lectures/161/RSA-lecture.pdf claims that $ n = 5 \times 11 = 55 $ as the minimal example of RSA key.

I would like to know why $ n = 2 \times 5 = 10 $ is not the minimal example. For example,

\begin{align*}
p &= 2 \\
q &= 5 \\
n = pq &= 10 \\
\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1) &= 4 \\
e &= 3 \\
d &= 3 \\
\end{align*}

These numbers seem valid because $ e $ is coprime to $ \phi(n) $ and $ ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$.

Both encryption and decryption seems to work fine with this. Let the message $ m = 8 $. Therefore the ciphertext is $ m^e \text{ mod } n = 2.$ The plaintext can be retrieved again as $ 2^d \text{ mod } n = 8.$

Why is $ n = 2 \times 5 = 10 $ not the smallest $ n $ for which the RSA encryption and decryption works fine?

Comment: They may have some implicit cryptographic strength requirements, such as $e\neq d$. But formally, it seems to me like it works.

Comment: If $ e \neq d $ is necessary, I would like to know why it is necessary. In that case, the next smallest example I can come up with is $ p = 2 $, $ q = 11 $, $n = 22$, $\phi(n) = 10$, $e = 3$, and $d = 7$ which is again inconsistent with the two articles I linked to in my question which are both inconsistent with each other.

Comment: If I actually knew how they've chosen their "smallest" examples, I would have posted an answer. And if I'm right about them having cryptographic strength requirements, then $e\neq d$ might not be the only cryptographic requirement they have. I did say "such as".

Comment: @Arthur I understand you. My previous question is not directed to you in particular but at anyone who could answer and clarify these things. I also wonder if it makes sense to think about cryptographic strength when the purpose is to find the smallest example for which the algorithm works because $ n $ being so small and easily factorizable makes cryptographic strength irrelevant, in my opinion.

Comment: @Moo Since $ n = 10 $ in my scheme we can only encrypt and decrypt numbers less than 10. The claimed minimums may or may not allow decryption of the alphabet A-Z depending on how they are encoded. If we encode A=0, B=1, ..., Z=25, then the claimed minimums would allow the encryption and decryption of A-Z. What's your point?

Comment: @Moo If the message $m < 10$ as it should be in my scheme, I don't see any repeat codes for ciphertext. In fact, the RSA algorithm guarantees that when the $m < n$ each $m$ will map to a unique ciphertext $c$.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the two papers. Clearly, strength is not the point, even $p,q$ of the order of about a hundred are open to attacks by hand/calculator.

Firstly $e\neq d$ is an absolute requirement for the definition of RSA since in practice $e$ is public and $d$ is private (needs to be kept secret) so both cannot be the same.

The other problem is that one chooses odd primes for RSA. The reason being if you choose $p=2,$ then your $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)=q-1,$ directly reveals the value of $p$. The reason this is important is that the valid user in posession of the secret key $e,$ also knows $p$ and $q$ (it's been proved that knowing $(n,e)$ you can find $p,q$) and thus can break the system.

In fact the exponentiation for decryption $C^d$ are performed separately mod $p$ and $q$  by the legitimate user for efficiency, and then the Chinese Remainder Theorem is used to obtain $C^d$ modulo $n.$

What if we chose the smaller prime to be $p=3$? This presents a problem for the popular choice of exponent $e=3.$ By Fermat's little theorem, $$a^p\equiv a~(\textrm{mod}~p),$$ for all integers $a$ which means that the subgroup of multiplication modulo $p=3,$ is "inactive" in some sense in the exponentiation operation and then $q$ could be discovered by a cryptanalyst.

In summary, the smaller prime must be at least $p=5.$ Taking $p=5,$ the smallest $q$ would be 7, otherwise taking the integer square root of $n$ is equivalent to factorisation.

If $p=5,q=7$ then $\phi(n)=24,$ which violates the requirement $gcd(e,\phi(n))=1,$ for the exponent $e=5.$

So take $p=5,q=11$ to get $n=55,$ ruling out $n=33,$ as I explained above.

Comment: So what is the smallest $n = pq$ for which the RSA encryption and decryption works?

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: I don't understand why $ e \neq d $ is necessary. Sure, $ e $ is public but the attacker may not know that the secret $ d $ equals $ e $. He still needs to brute force $ d $ to know that it is same as $ e $. The same thing holds true for $ p = 2 $. The attacker still needs to factor $ n $ to determine $ p = 2 $. These are perils of small numbers not a specific choice of $ p $ and $ q $. But we have already established that strength is not of concern because we want to demonstrate RSA with small numbers.